# Explain how the 1/2 theta angle was detrmined

Tags: trigonometry

[How did they get the 1/2 theta angle?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BnEW.jpg)

The 1/2 theta angle in the pic was determined from the theta angle. How can you know given theta that that other angle is 1/2 theta?

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be because
that other line
that makes up the
$\frac12\theta$
is perpendicular
to the line
next to the "R"
and the inner angle
is
$\frac12\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Because tangent lines are always perpendicular to the radius.   So the angle difference between two lines will be equal to the angle difference between the two lines that are perpendicular to the lines.  In this case the angle between the radii is $\frac 12 \theta$, so the angle between the two tangent lines which are perpendicular to the radii will also be $\frac 12 \theta$.

Comment: I think you got it. Wow that was not obvious. Thanks!!

Comment: The drawing was a bit convoluted.  But if you look only at the lines and angles it becomes clear.